# Как сохранить html код в базу данных ?

Tags: html, php, mysql

Есть форма:

```
<form action='post.php' method='post'>
    <div style='width: 995px; height: 15px; line-height: 15px; text-align: left; padding-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 15px; color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7); text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 1px 1px 0px;'>
         Оставить коментарий
    </div>
    <input type='hidden' name='poluchatel' value='$myrow[email]'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$myrow[id]'>
    <textarea required placeholder='Ваше сообщение ...' class='answer' name='text'></textarea>
    <input class='s-answer' type='submit' name='submit' value='Отправить'>
    <div class='a-answer'>
        <div class='general'>
            <div class='attach'>
                Прикрепить
            </div>
            <div class='attach-m'>
                <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='90' height='70'>
                <tr>
                    <td width='20'>
                        <a href='#attach_photo'>
                        <img style='margin-left: 5px;' src='images/photo.png'>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a class='font' href='#attach_photo'>
                        Фото </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width='20'>
                        <a href='#'>
                        <img style='margin-left: 5px;' src='images/movie.png'>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a class='font' href='#'>
                        Видео </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width='20'>
                        <a href='#'>
                        <img style='margin-left: 5px;' src='images/music.png'>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a class='font' href='#'>
                        Аудио </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

При помощи этой формы мне необходимо передавать html код в базу данных, но ни один тег не сохраняется! Почему ?

Вот код обработчика :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include ("bd.php");

    if (!empty($_SESSION['email']) and !empty($_SESSION['password'])) {
        $email = $_SESSION['email'];
        $password = $_SESSION['password'];
        $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'",$db); 
        $myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2); 
        if (empty($myrow2['id'])) {exit("Вход на эту страницу разрешен только зарегистрированным пользователям!");}
    }
    else { exit("Вход на эту страницу разрешен только зарегистрированным пользователям!"); }

    if (isset($_POST['id'])) { $id = $_POST['id'];}
    if (isset($_POST['text'])) { $text = $_POST['text'];}
    if (isset($_POST['poluchatel'])) { $poluchatel = $_POST['poluchatel'];}
    $author = $_SESSION['email'];
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    if (empty($author) or empty($text) or empty($poluchatel) or empty($date)) { exit ("Вы ввели не всю информацию, вернитесь назад и заполните все поля");}

    $result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages (author, poluchatel, date, text) VALUES ('$author','$poluchatel','$date','$text')",$db);

?>
```

Comment: html-код пишется в textarea?

Comment: Да. html-код пишется в textarea. Я нашол почему он не заносится в базу :) 

Для занесеня в базу я использую вот такой запрос: 
INSERT INTO private_messages (author, poluchatel, date, text) VALUES ('$author','$poluchatel','$date','$text')

Где в $text хранится какой либо html код. Элемент $text находится в кавычках и в html коде кавычки тоже встречаются, короче они все путоются и в базу нифига не сохраняется. Но как это исправить я незнаю ... Помогите !!!

Comment: Экранируйте данные перед внесением в БД, напр., **mysql_real_escape_string()**. Причем любые данные. Еще лучше - используйте PDO.

Comment: Deonis спасибо рабоьоет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Извините, но очень много лишнего кода - всё не читал.

Проблема прямой записи html-кода при апдейте таблицы очевидна (лишние кавычки, спец. символы и тп.) и есть несколько решений, использующих инструменты php:

1) например, ***htmlspecialchars()***

```
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
```

и соответственно обратная функция при выводе: ***htmlspecialchars_decode()***

2) если уверены, что проблема только в двойных или одинарных кавычках, то подойдет и ***addcslashes()***,  и при выводе соответственно ***stripslashes()***

3) а также упомянутый ***mysql_real_escape_string()*** при желании вписать всё что угодно в запрос SQL.

На мой взгляд и хранить, и выводить html-код удобнее и надежнее первым способом.

Answer (score 3):

---ОФФТОП---

Часть кода про проверку почтового ящика и пароля явно неверная. Вам не за чем здесь проверять существование переменных, а затем еще в базе проверять этого пользователя. Это нужно делать только на этапе авторизации, и затем создать в сессии какой-нибудь флаг, что пользователь авторизован, плюс некоторые данные в сессию записать, такие как: почтовый ящик, группа, может быть имя, ник и т.д. В итоге здесь у вас должен остаться такой кусочек кода:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['auth']) || $_SESSION['auth'] == false){
    exit('Вы не авторизованы');
}
```

А лучше вообще это все вынести в отдельный класс-синглтон, получится нечто такое:

```
if(!User::authCheck()) exit;
```

Comment: @MuFF, в таком случае лучше вообще использовать `__call`

Comment: здесь User - это модель пользователя, а authCheck - один из методов модели, который проверят авторизован ли пользователь.. или вы какой-то другой контекст применения __call имели в виду?

Comment: @MuFF, имел ввиду применять такую проверку в __call, т.е. если архитектура приложения правильна с точки зрения ООП, то, в зависимости от метода и свойств класса, делать проверку (Санкционировать пользователя на выполнение действия/запроса и т.д. или же нет). Написал 1 раз и забыл. Часто сталкивался с тем, что подобные вызовы `if(!User::authCheck()) exit;` вставлялись куда только их душе было угодно.

Comment: согласен )