# Перевод текста на сайтe

Tags: php

Как быть с переводом текста который содержит в себе html теги? Вот допустим надо перевести данный текст,который содержит в себе теги `<i>,<strong>,<span> и даже <a>`.Вставлять в базу все вместе с html?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как связан перевод со вставлять в базу. Для перевода надо наверное очистить от тэгов. Для хранения - смотря что вы хотите, текст хранить или html разметку

Comment: В админке будет возможность добавлять перевод переменным,вот и спрашиваю,правильно ли будет если текст содержит в себе html теги сохранять его вместе с ним в базу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вордпрессе делают так. Вот английский оригинал:

```
"Read the <a href=\"%s\" target=\"_blank\">bug report</a> page. Some of the guidelines there may help you figure out what went wrong."
```

Вот русский перевод:

```
"Прочтите страницу для <a href=\"%s\" target=\"_blank\">сообщения об ошибках</a>. Некоторые рекомендации могут помочь вам понять, что нужно исправить."
```

Вордпресс использует [gettext](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext#.D0.98.D1.81.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.B7.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5):

1. строки для перевода обозначают их английским оригиналом, а не специальным идентификатором;
2. переводы хранят в специальных файлах, которые удобно редактировать с помощью [Poedit](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poedit);
3. из кода программы к ним обращаются с помощью функции `gettext`, её аналога или короткого синонима `_`.

**UPD**.

Чтобы подставить в строку значения переменных, строки из перевода форматируют с помощью функции [printf](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.printf.php). В примере [про использование getext](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext#.D0.94.D0.BB.D1.8F_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B3.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.BC.D0.B8.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B0) приведён код:

```
printf(_("Hello! My name is %s.\n"), name);
```

В нём `printf` подставляет вместо `%s` строку со значением, полученным от `name`.

Comment: А если в строке которую нужно перевести еще надо будет подставить значения переменных каких то? как быть в данной ситуации

Comment: @quaresma89 [По ссылке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext#.D0.94.D0.BB.D1.8F_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B3.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.BC.D0.B8.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B0) дан пример кода: `printf(_("Hello! My name is %s.\n"), name);`. В нём функция  `printf` [форматирует строку](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.printf.php) из перевода и в частности, подставляет вместо `%s` значение, полученное из `name`.

Comment: Спасибо за хорошие советы!

Comment: Вы описали выше как переводить текст когда в нем содержится HTML.Я так понимаю он вставляет прямо в базу,без никакого форматирования

Comment: @quaresma89 [gettext](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext) хранит переводы в фалах с расширениями `.po`, `.mo` и т.д. Есть программы, помогающие переводчикам работать с этими файлами. Например, Poedit.

Comment: Просто в моем случае нужно написать функционал которые позволяет добавлять переменые и перевод к ним из админки,вот и действую по аналогии работы gettext.Только вот как хранить HTML так и не разобрался

Comment: @quaresma89 Вот [толковый ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/155411/208926) на этот вопрос.